# Concatenando arrays

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

Quería implementar un método el cual recibe como parámetros un array con elementos de tipo `String` y un valor de tipo `String`. El método concatena los elementos del array con el simbolo pasado como segundo parámetro. El problema es que no termino de entender el retorno en los métodos

```
public static String concatenando(String[] array, String valor) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String concatenacion = array[i] + valor;
  }/* Si retorno el valor antes de cerrar el bucle me salta un error porque
      el método necesita retorna algo*/

  return concatenacion; // Si retorno aquí la variable concatenacion no existe
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  String[] words = {"Uso", "Array", "Java"};
  System.out.println(concatenando(words,"-")); // "Uso-Array-Java"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
public static String concatenando(String[] array, String valor) {
    String concatenacion = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        concatenacion = concatenacion + (concatenacion.isEmpty() ? array[i] : valor + array[i]);
    }
    return concatenacion;
}
```

También podrías hacerlo usando el método join de la clase String:

```
public static String concatenando(String[] array, String valor) {
    return String.join(valor, array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si retornas dentro del ciclo ni siquiera le darías tiempo al ciclo de completarse. Algunas veces eso está bien pero para tu caso no es así. Además de que debes indicar algún valor de retorno fuera del ciclo también dado que podría darse el caso de que ni siquiera entre al ciclo.

Si retornas fuera del ciclo debes declarar la variable fuera del ciclo también sino el compilador te lanza un error porque no has declarado la variable de la forma correcta.

Prueba esto:

```
public static String concatenando(String[] array, String valor) {
    String concatenacion = ""; // Preparo la variable que retornaré

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        concatenacion += array[i] + valor; // Concateno usando la variable destinada para ello
    }

    return concatenacion;    // Retorno la variable
}
```

Comment: @LearningDeveloper Con la sentencia: `array[i]` se obtiene la dirección base de un objeto de tipo `String` y con `charAt` podemos extraer X caracter de una cadena..